# Radio changes value Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/TcNhLcSyDELsPESh9eou?p=preview

How to make that value will be changes always after selection two radio?
Can anybody help me with it?

```
    $scope.opts = {
            val1: false,
            val2: false,
            val3: false,
            val4: false };  

   $scope.computedTotal = function () {   
 var opts = $scope.opts;
   if(opts.val1==true && opts.val3==true){
   return $scope.basPremium * 0.92;    
 } else if(opts.val1==true && opts.val4==true){
   return ($scope.basPremium * 0.95)*1.04;    
 } else if(opts.val2==true && opts.val3==true) {
   return ($scope.basPremium * 0.98)*1.08;    
 } else if(opts.val2==true && opts.val4==true) {
   return $scope.basPremium * 1.12;    
 } };
```

---

```
<input type="radio" name="rdoResult" ng-model="opts.val1" ng-value="true"/> bezszkodowe ubezpieczenie 5%<br>
<input type="radio" name="rdoResult" ng-model="opts.val2" ng-value="true"/> za wystąpienie szkody w okresie ubezpiczenie zwyżka 8%<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="paid"      ng-model="opts.val3" ng-value="true"/> płatność jednorazowa żniżka 2%<br>
<input type="radio" name="paid"      ng-model="opts.val4" ng-value="true"/> płatność w 4 ratach zwyżka 4%<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program is run for the first time, all your model attributes have default values set. So when you start selecting the radio button for the first time, AngularJS detects the changes, and calls the `computeTotal()` function.

But once all the possible radio button combinations are selected, the model values are set and since no change is detected, `computeTotal()` isn't called (until you change the input value).

### Solution:

Try resetting `opts.val` to `false` after the the `computeTotal()` function value is returned.